# How to show green/red colors in Github PRs showing code coverage

Tags: github, code-coverage, codecov

Codecov has data for my repository's code coverage, and the report it shows is useful, e.g.

[image: actual]

But it would be much more useful if I can show code coverage in the /files page when looking at a PR on Github itself, i.e. something like this:

[image: expected]

According to Codecov docs, there used to be a Google Chrome extension (Sourcegraph) that added the color overlay, but it was deprecated in September 2022.

> https://docs.codecov.com/docs/browser-extension
> https://github.com/codecov/sourcegraph-codecov/blob/master/README.md
> Sourcegraph extensions have been deprecated with the September 2022 Sourcegraph release. Learn more.

So, how can I accomplish what I want? I like the inline coloring because it lets me know immediately if the PR tries to merge code that isn't covered. With my current setup I need to look at the codecov report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom from Codecov here. Although the Sourcegraph extension is deprecated, we are currently working on bringing back a browser extension to do this. The project is open-sourced [here](https://github.com/codecov/codecov-browser-extension) if you want to follow along.

We are planning to launch sometime by the end of this year.

Comment: This is very cool! I tried it out though and I can't see any coloring on https://github.com/openfga/openfga/pull/624, for example. I'm logged in to GitHub and Codecov

Comment: The extension is definitely in super super beta right now, so I can't promise anything works. I would suggest coming back in a month or two to start to see results, and I'm sure that the team would love any suggestions or feedback.